# decode protobuf file returned by google cloud storage python api

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-play-console, google-python-api

I am trying to automatically download earnings report from Google Play through Google Cloud Storage and their client api library for python, `googleapiclient`.

I use python 3.6.5 (Anaconda distribution) on Windows 10:

```
client_email = '...@...iam.gserviceaccount.com'
json_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\...'
cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_...'
report_to_download = 'sales/salesreport_201806.zip'

json_obj = json.loads(open(json_file).read())
_private_key = json_obj['private_key']
_private_key_id = json_obj['private_key_id']
_token_uri = json_obj['token_uri']
_client_id = json_obj['client_id']


credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials(
    service_account_email = client_email,
    private_key_id = _private_key_id,
    token_uri = _token_uri,
    client_id = _client_id,
    scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only',
    signer = crypt.Signer.from_string(_private_key), )

storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

request = storage.objects().get_media(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket,
                                      object=report_to_download)
response = request.execute()
```

However, I get some protocol buffer file as `response`, which starts like this: 
`b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xdb\xa3\xe4L\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00PlayApps_201806.csv'`

I cannot figure out which decoder I should use to get `response` in a better format (when downloaded manually from Google Play, the report is `.csv` file in a `.zip` archive). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a protobuf. It is a zip file. The clues

- the filename is 'sales/salesreport_201806.zip'
- the first few bytes contain "PK", (as in [PKZip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKZIP))